# Unable to find custom template when using a console controller inside a module

Tags: templating, php, emails, modules

I'm creating my first module. Inside this module, I check a few entries for some conditions, and if all conditions are met, I want to send out a personal email.

Everything worked, but I wanted to clean up my code and put the email body inside a template file so it's more organized. This is where I'm having trouble.

Whenever I run the command ./craft check-date/send-mail, I keep getting the following error:

```
Unable to find the template “checkdate/emails/_email.twig”.
```

Here is a striped down version of my module:

**modules/checkdate/src/CheckDate.php**

```php
<?php

namespace modules\checkdate;

use Craft;
use yii\base\Module as BaseModule;

/**
 * CheckDate module
 *
 * @method static CheckDate getInstance()
 */
class CheckDate extends BaseModule
{
    public function init(): void
    {
        Craft::setAlias('@modules/check-date', __DIR__);

        // Set the controllerNamespace based on whether this is a console or web request
        if (Craft::$app->request->isConsoleRequest) {
            $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\checkdate\\console\\controllers';
        } else {
            $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\checkdate\\controllers';
        }

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

**modules/checkdate/src/console/controllers/SendMailController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace modules\checkdate\console\controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\console\Controller;
use craft\elements\Entry;

use craft\helpers\Html;
use craft\helpers\Template;
use craft\mail\Message;

use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;

/**
 * Greet Controller
 */
class SendMailController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Issues a greeting to new Craft developers.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        // Get all entries in your section
        $entries = Entry::find()
            ->section('dates')
            ->fieldSendedMail(false)
            ->all();

        foreach ($entries as $entry) {

            // Variables
            $title = $entry->title;

            // Send email with HTML body
            try {
                // Render the HTML template with variables
                $htmlBody = Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate(
                    'checkdate/emails/_email.twig',
                    [
                        'name' => $title
                    ]
                );
                $mailer = Craft::$app->getMailer();
                $message = new Message();
                $message->setTo('recipient@example.com');
                $message->setSubject('Subject of the Email');
                $message->setHtmlBody($htmlBody);
                $mailer->send($message);
            } catch (InvalidConfigException $e) {
                // Handle any exceptions that occur during email sending
                Craft::error('Error sending email for entry ' . $entry->id . ': ' . $e->getMessage(), 'send-mail');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**modules/checkdate/src/templates/emails/_email.twig**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Email Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>{{ title }},</p>
        <p>This is your custom email content.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**config/app.php**

```php
<?php
/**
 * Yii Application Config
 *
 * Edit this file at your own risk!
 *
 * The array returned by this file will get merged with
 * vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/app.php and app.[web|console].php, when
 * Craft's bootstrap script is defining the configuration for the entire
 * application.
 *
 * You can define custom modules and system components, and even override the
 * built-in system components.
 *
 * If you want to modify the application config for *only* web requests or
 * *only* console requests, create an app.web.php or app.console.php file in
 * your config/ folder, alongside this one.
 */

use craft\helpers\App;
use modules\checkdate\CheckDate;

return [
    'id' => App::env('APP_ID') ?: 'CraftCMS',
    'modules' => [
        'check-date' => CheckDate::class
    ],
    'bootstrap' => [
        'check-date'
    ],
];
```

**composer.json**

```json
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "modules\\checkdate\\": "modules/checkdate/src/"
        }
    }
```

How do i access my template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike plugins, modules have to register their own [template root](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/template-roots.html).

Stick something like this in your module's `init()` method:

```php
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\events\RegisterTemplateRootsEvent;
use craft\web\View;

...

Event::on(
    View::class,
    View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS,
    function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {
        if (is_dir($baseDir = $this->getBasePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates')) {
            $e->roots[$this->id] = $baseDir;
        }
    }
);
```

This will register a template root `'check-date'` (i.e. the ID for your module, as per the config in your `config/app.php` file), that points to the `modules/checkdate/src/templates` folder.

This means that you'll also have to correct your email template path from

```php
'checkdate/emails/_email.twig'
```

to

```php
'check-date/emails/_email.twig'
```

It's also, generally, a good idea to be explicit about the view mode when rendering custom templates. In this case, you'll want Craft to use the 'CP' view mode, so the full `View::render()` method call should look like this:

```php
use craft\web\View;

...

$htmlBody = Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate(
    'check-date/emails/_email.twig',
    [
        'name' => $title
    ],
    View::TEMPLATE_MODE_CP
);
```

Comment: Couldn't find that myself! Thanks for clearing that out, works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to switch the `templateMode` to be `TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE` in your call to `renderTemplate()` -- otherwise it'll default to attempting to load templates from the main Craft app.

```php
$htmlBody = Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate(
    'checkdate/emails/_email.twig',
    ['name' => $title],
    \craft\web\View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE
);
```

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-web-controller.html#method-rendertemplate

Comment: Hi James,

I'm a step closer, but now it will look in Craft's main template folder. Is there a way to keep everything inside the module folder?

So with you're snippet it looks for /templates/checkdate/emails/_email.twig -> works well tho.

But can i make it so it uses /modules/checkdate/src/templates/checkdate/emails/_email.twig instead?

Comment: This answer assumes that the `email.twig` template is in the _site_ template folder (i.e. `templates/checkdate/emails/_email.twig`). I believe OP wants to render the template from a folder inside their module's folder, in which case `TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE` is wrong.

Comment: Ah right I hadn't considered that approach. Interesting. Personally if it's a _module_ I'd prefer to keep all my templates together (especially since emails would likely `extend` some shared email layout templates. Only reason I'd consider bundling it together would be if it's a _plugin_ to be distributed.

Comment: @JamesSmith That's completely valid IMO. I've done both; the approach typically depends on how tightly coupled the module is to the actual site/build. For modules that are mostly self-contained, I think it's nice to keep everything pertaining to that module, including templates, in the module source folder.